# Is there a way to fix SwiftLint's trailing whitespace violation?

Tags: swift, xcode, whitespace, swiftlint

I have a method that has has a closing bracket at line 20, I want my next method to start at line 23 because I want line 22 to have a comment. This will leave line 21 to have the one space between these two methods, but because line 22 is a comment SwiftLint will throw a "Trailing Whitespace Violation". Is there any way to fix this? [image: White Space Violation Code]

Comment: Are you sure the issue is the line? I suspect you have some spaces/tabs on it, and it's asking that the line should be empty.

Comment: Is there trailing whitespace after the closure bracket `}`? Also did you enable trailing_whitespace - I think it's off by default.

Comment: After you change your editor settings to trim trailing whitespace, if you've got a lot of these in your project, you can remove them all from your project by going to the global “Find navigator” (command+`4`), doing doing a regex-based find-and-replace (e.g. of “`[ \t]+$`”).

Answer (score 17):

Trailing whitespace violation doesn't mean that there is an empty line, but rather that there is some unnecessary whitespace (not linebreaks, but tabs/spaces).

You can automatically fix trailing whitespacing by turning on the relevant feature in Xcode. You can find it in Xcode Preferences: `Text Editing/Editing/While editing`, turn on both *"Automatically trim trailing whitespace"* and *"Including whitespace-only lines"*.

Comment: I'll add: Editor/Invisibles would show/hide invisible characters, and you shall see then the spaces like that.

Comment: I'll add: If enabling this from Xcode Preferences, doesn't seem to work for existing code, try to cut-paste the same code and ta-da, it will fix itself after pasting again.